# How to run TestNG.xml with Datagenerators

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

When i run the TestNG.xml, the tests that have data generators associated with them do not run. Only test without data generators run. I am getting `NullPointerExcetion`.

If I only run the class with data generator by itself it works. When I add another class, the error is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to say Dataprovider.

If you want to use dataprovider which is located in Class 1 in Class 2, then you have to use @Test(dataProvider = "dataProviderName", dataProviderClass = Class1.class) syntax.

Additionally if it is in another package then you have to import the class first and then use the above syntax.

Comment: I added both the code and the package. It runs smoothly from the class. But when I run it from the testing.xml, the BeforeMethod executed and not the Test method. Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: Please share your code snippets of testng.xml, dataproviderclass and the class in which dataprovider has been used.